# Bootstrap responsiveness not according to screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

So I am using Bootstrap in my Django project and I have a few problems with the xs-sm-md-lg responsive classes.

For example, when debugging with Chrome, I can see that the screen width is 1080x380 but I can already see my two `col-lg-6`-wide columns side by side.
When looking at their row, its size is 1200x740 pixels.

I am using bootstrap#3.3.5 and Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit) on Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27).

Here is my HTML head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="/static/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection">
...
</head>
```

Here are my row and columns:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="content">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 background-purple text-center">
            <h2 class="title-blah">Some text</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>Some text</p>
        </div> <!-- col -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 background-blue hire-main-block">
            <h2 class="text-center title-hire">
                {% trans "Recrutez avec COOP-TIME !" %}
            </h2>
            <hr>
            <form ...>...</form>
        </div> <!-- col -->
    </div> <!-- row -->
</div> <!-- container -->
```

So it seems that Bootstrap displays columns correctly (their parent row's width is >= 1200px) but not according to the screen size (Chrome shows a width <1200px). Which indicators should I trust when debugging and developing? Did I misunderstand something in the [Bootstrap grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)?

Comment: I believe Chrome is showing you the *outer* width, which is the width plus margin, border.

Comment: But the row's container is a `container-fluid`so there may be like 1 to 10 px less from what Chrome says to the row width...

Comment: What do you mean by "Chrome is showing you" what are you using to get thta number??

Comment: Everything is working fine! Maybe there is a problem with the class `hire-main-block`.

Comment: I resized Firefox and Safari to the exact same width as Chrome and I do not have the two col-lg-6 side by side, which is the expected behavior. What could possibly be wrong with Chrome here ?

Comment: @Adelphia: I am inspecting elements with Chrome. On the top right corner, it shows the size when I resize the window.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but Chrome is working just fine now. I just restarted my Mac multiple times since the ticket was created.